# Lightweight Ubuntu for networking purposes

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

What is best lightweight Ubuntu only for networking purposes?

I'm doing a project based on IPv6 and I want to test it. Lot of mini distributions are there. But actually I couldn't find a better one for my project. I want to run 3,4 VMs under Ubuntu.GUI is not necessary.

Thank you!

Comment: This question should be related to Ubuntu specific problems. Asking for a comparison of Linux OS for a particular purpose is more oriented towards http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Adjusted the question a bit to be in scope, if you want to ask about other distros including then you need to do what @LuisAlvarado is saying.

Comment: @sura2k - the key to virtualisation is memory and CPU (lots or cores/processors) - if you include the details of your host we should be able to advise you better.

Comment: @fossfreedom - 2GB Ram, 2.0GHz Core2Duo, Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Assuming you are running virtual machines with guests that are ubuntu server based with no gui and just minimal networking tools, my judgement would be that a virtualbox type solution would cope with approx 4-6 VMs.  With a GUI you will be lucky to get 1 or 2 VMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download) installer, if you select during the installation to install servers later on it will install the bare minimal to have a running Ubuntu installation without having to go thru manual configurations.

I would recommend this over other solutions because:

- It will leave you with a running system with minimal services running
- Minimal configuration necessary, installer will do the work for you
- Very easy to install
- Without running many service the memory / CPU footprint in the host
  will be minimal

The performance of the VMs will depend on the host specs but since you have no GUI and almost no services running (unless you want them installed and running) the necessary specs for the host will be very low.

You will be able to run a few of these inside VMs on a normal day to day computer (for testing / development purposes ofc).

Comment: Is it possible to run several VM instance without slow down the root os?