# Establish a virtual network using VM with minimal-distributions

Tags: networking, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lightweight Ubuntu for networking purposes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82064/lightweight-ubuntu-for-networking-purposes)

What is best lightweight Ubuntu only for networking purposes?

I'm doing a project related to networking based on IPv6 and I want to test it.

So I need to create a IPv6 Virtual Network in my Linux OS (I use Ubuntu). Also I need to create some virtual hosts in my virtual network and setup static ips (local ips) for each and every host. And I need to run a terminal on each virtual host.

I figured running several instances of a VM is the only way to establish a network. Lots of mini-distributions are there, but I couldn't find a good one for my project. Networking configurations should be there.

Comment: I just set up 4 Ubuntu VMs in VirtualBox, plain old "Ubuntu Server". You only need to install one, and you can clone the others. I'm running them on an old single core celeron, and it works really well. Is that along the lines of what you want? How many machines are we talking about?